# Padding in tabular caused by \left

Tags: tables, alignment

in tabular environment, I would like to use `\left.` in one row but not in some another one. It results in items not verticaly aligned in the table column.

Here is the affected minimal example:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    one & $85$ \\
    two & $\left.85\right\rbrace$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

looks like this, see the right column:

[image: display sample]

How to make those `85` numbers be aligned vertically?

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason for writing `$\left.85\right\rbrace$` instead of `$85\rbrace$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove the `\nulldelimiterspace`:

```
\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace 85\right\}
```

On the other hand, I can't see what good the `\left`-`\right` pair is doing.

Comment: Thanks, the question was simplified, for completeness the real case I wanted to solve is having the \rbrace span multiple table rows. I found a solution here, but it introduces the space, when there are more rows around without the brace: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448123/257708

Comment: @PavelBazika I added an answer with `nicematrix` that's very handy for such jobs.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using `\right` you could specify the size directly and avoid `\left.` entirely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    one & $85$ \\
    two & $85\big\}\Big\}\bigg\}\Bigg\}$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The space of the null delimiter is set by `\nulldelimiterspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    one & $85$ \\
    two & $\left.85\right\rbrace$ \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]